# Changing predefined style attribuite using Javascript

Tags: javascript

If the style attribute is already set to display: none; how can I change it to be display:block; when calling the toggleControls function?

```
function toggleControls() {
    var leControls = document.getElementsByClassName('le-controls'); 
    for(var i = 0; i < leControls.length; i++) { leControls[i].style.display = 'none'; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check if it's already `none`:

```
var style, leControls = document.getElementsByClassName('le-controls');
for (var i = 0; i < leControls.length; i++) {
    if ('none' == leControls[i].style.display) {
        style = 'block';
    }
    else {
        style = 'none';
    }
    leControls[i].style.display = style;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. Would you mine explaining what's going on there, or putting that into context with the rest of the function?

Comment: @rick I added back the snipped parts of the function